# Volley not able to connect to server in some devices

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm have a an app that uses volley to connect to a server to fetch some online songs and download data in JSON format. I have deployed this app to the playstore. But many of my users are complaining that the online songs are not showing up. Everytime the OnErrorResponse method is called for these users. I have tested it on my device and my friends'. Everything works fine. What could be the problem?

PS : I'm not using any retry policies or custom headers.

Code:

```
  private void getNewSongs() {

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, newSongsUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            JSONObject artistObject = null;
            String artist = "";
            String albumID = "";
            String artistID = null;

            try {


                JSONObject songListObjects = response.getJSONObject("new_song");

                    if(songListObjects.has("data")){

                        JSONObject data = songListObjects.getJSONObject("data");

                        if(data.has("song_list")) {

                            JSONArray songList = data.getJSONArray("song_list");

                            for (int i=0;i<5;i++){

                                JSONObject songListObject = songList.getJSONObject(i);

                                if (songListObject.has("mid")) {

                                    Log.e("SongListObject has", "songmid");
                                    String songID = songListObject.getString("mid");
                                    String songTitle = songListObject.getString("name");
                                    long duration = songListObject.getLong("interval") * 1000;
                                    Log.e("Title:", songTitle);
                                    Log.e("Duration:", String.valueOf(duration));

                                    JSONObject albumObject  = songListObject.getJSONObject("album");

                                    if(albumObject.has("mid")){

                                        albumID = albumObject.getString("mid");


                                    }



                                    JSONArray artistArray = songListObject.getJSONArray("singer");

                                    for (int j = 0; j < artistArray.length(); j++) {

                                        artistObject = artistArray.getJSONObject(j);

                                        if (j == 0) {

                                            if (artistObject.has("name")) {


                                                Log.e("ArtistObject: ", "has name");

                                                artist = artistObject.getString("name");
                                                artistID = artistObject.getString("mid");

                                            }
                                        } else {

                                            if (artistObject.has("name")) {

                                                Log.e("ArtistObject: ", "has name");

                                                artist = artist + " ft. " + artistObject.getString("name");

                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                    String songData = "http://xx.x.x.xx.com/xxxx" + songID + ".xx?;
                                    //   String songData = "http://xx.x.xx.xx.com/xxxx"+songID+".xxx?;
                                    String albumArtURL = "https://y.xx.xx/x/xx/x" + alx+bumID + ".jpg";
                                    SongInfoModel songInfoModel = new SongInfoModel(123, songTitle,artistID, ((artist == null || (artist.length() == 0)) ? "Unknown" : artist), duration, songData, albumArtURL);
                                    SoundCloudNewSongs.add(songInfoModel);

                                    if (getView() != null){

                                        getView().findViewById(R.id.onlineProgressLoad).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        getView().findViewById(R.id.mainLayout).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }



                                }

                            }


                        }
                    }



                newSongsAdapter = new NewSongsAdapter(SoundCloudNewSongs, getContext(),listenerOnline,1);
                recyclerView_newSongs.setAdapter(newSongsAdapter);


            } catch (JSONException e) {


            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {




        }
    });

    songQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

}
```

Comment: Hard to identify problem, if app is working in your devices.
Use fabric like crashlytics in your app. Code for sending custom crash log on receiving onError of volley. Push an update on playstore. Then you will able to find on fabric where the issue is.

Comment: @Sebin Paul: Without providing the log of what is the error, it is very difficult to give solution. You try checking it in very slow internet connection. Then you might be able to figure it out. Try increasing the request timeout time.

Comment: I never said the app crashes. But the songs won't show up. The OnErrorResponse method is called. I know this can happen when the internet connection is slow. But some users with quite good internet connections too are having this problem.

Comment: Consider using crashlytics.